# Sql SELECT returns rows while selecting from mysql table via toad but returns zero rows while selecting from code igniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, select

I'm working on an application that uses codeigniter and oracle database. I also need to get data from a separate mysql database. So I created a DBLINK and connected to mysql database via oracle database. And when I query mysql database from TOAD, it returns the rows. But when I select query from codeignitor, it returns zero rows.

And also, I can insert and update data in mysql table. Just the select query returns zero rows.

Here is the select query

`select * from "table_name"@dblink;`

This query works fine with TOAD. But returns zero rows in codeigniter.
"table_name" is mysql table name

And here is the CI code.

```
$sql = "select * from \"table_name\"@dblink";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Ok, would you provide us some code!? the queris ?!

Comment: I have updated the post with the sql query.

Comment: Can you show us the CI code you are using to fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

This should be your CI db query with Active Record.

```
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
}
```

[Refer the CodeIgnitor user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: I'm using oracle db as default db, not mysql. I have no problem in fetching for default database. The problem is I have a distributed database system that links mysql database to default database i.e oracle. And i'm not being able to fetch data from that mysql database.